# Declaring template functions with dependent types of arguments in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

In C++20, a template function can be declared in a simplified way using `auto` keyword and omitting `template<class T>` prefix. But if the second/third/… argument type of a template function depends on the first template argument type, is the declaration with `auto` equivalent?

Consider an old-style template example:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T x, std::optional<T> y, std::array<char,sizeof(T)> z);
```

The same template function declaration with `auto`-syntax will be:

```
void g(auto x, std::optional<decltype(x)> y, std::array<char,sizeof(x)> z);
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2019 16.11.2 rejects the second variant with the errors:

```
error C3539: a template-argument cannot be a type that contains 'auto'
error C3540: sizeof cannot be applied to a type that contains 'auto'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vc6bE14jh

Is it just a limitation/bug of Visual Studio?

Comment: @JeJo: That’s about template parameters, not function parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is an MSVC bug, but `g` and `f` are not the same here because `g` deduces only from its **first** argument (which may or may not be what you want).